# Finding Replacement AC Condenser

Tags: toyota, ac, diy, condenser

I inherited a 1984 Toyota pick-up from my father when he passed 25 years ago.  The AC Condenser is leaking and needs to be replaced.  Toyota no longer makes the condenser, and I have been unable to find any aftermarket manufacturer who still makes the part or any of their stocking distributors who might have one in their inventory.  One radiator shop suggested I find a condenser that will fit (since I know the dimensions of the existing condenser) and then custom make the hoses and mounting brackets.

- Can I use a condenser from another vehicle?
- How can I go about fixing this without an original core?
- Would just finding a condenser core about the same size, then fitting new hoses and mounting brackets be all I'd need to do?

Comment: Look on eBay. Many discontinued things find a generic aftermarket home there.

Comment: I think the changes I've made to the question should allow it to be salvaged. Please consider retracting your close votes.

Comment: Great job, @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2.  Retracted.